# JTable get value from cell when is not submitted

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to get value from cell when its is no submitted (cell is in edit mode) - "real time"; Is it possible?

I tried this but it is working only if i submit data - press enter

```
int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
int col = jTable.getSelectedColumn();
String cellValue = jTable.getValueAt(row, col).toString();
```

I want to get on keypress cell value without exiting it, get this text real time while typing

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
          @Override
          public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {

              int row = jTable.getSelectedRow();
              int col = jTable.getSelectedColumn();


              if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                  if (jTable.isEditing())
                      jTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                  String cellValue = (jTable.getValueAt(row, col)!=null) ? jTable.getValueAt(row, col).toString() : "";
                  System.out.println(cellValue);
              }}
```

jTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing() -  cause ugly in/out animation while typing

@camickr Sorry for the confusion. Your solution is ok. 
I just needed to add jTable.editCellAt(row, col); to get back into edit mode.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cell is in edit mode

The editing must be stopped before the value is saved to the model.

The easiest way to do this is to use:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

when you create the table.

Now when you click on the button to do your processing the table loses focus so the data is saved.

Check out [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! if (table.isEditing())
    table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing(); works perfectly!

Comment: I have another question. Do you know how to return to selected cell editing without animation? I mean when i do stopCellEditing() it quits and when i type it turns to edit mode. How can i do it invisibly?

Comment: @Kmopsuy,  Your original question was answered and you "accepted" the answer. Why did you un-accept the answer? I did not suggest to use stopCellEditing() as you type each character. I have no idea why you added this code the key dispatcher.